# add an image as water mark for video with opacity size adjustment and opacity

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

I'm trying to add watermark for video but as any video editor I also want options of all opacity size and position I found for both opacity and position the below command does it but I missing with scaling the image

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -i test1.png -filter_complex "[1]format=rgba,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.25[logo];[0][logo]overlay=50:50" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert a scale filter after the ccm filter.

`format=rgba,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.25,scale=W:H`

Comment: yes buddy I tried but it's blurring the video
can u update with the full line of command thank you

Comment: Upscaling the video will soften it.